# I need to change regular pixel-based coordinates to chart based coordinates in Java. How?

Tags: java, graphics, charts, coordinates, pixel

I am creating a little minigame where you move blocks around a 27*27 grid.

Each square of the grid is 16*16 pixels.

I created the grid using the "drawLine" function from the awt Graphics. I created many lines that created a grid spanning the JFrame window/canvas. I need to assign each square in the grid to a sort of coordinate.

For example, if you've ever studied the Minecraft textures and/or made a texture pack, you've noticed the icons.png or texture.png. It's all a 256*256 grid of 16*16 squares that each have an image on it. When Notch (or Jens at the moment) needs to reference the image from the picture into the code. He basically thinks:

"Oh, well I need to find the image from coordinate (1, 3) in icons.png."

The 1 represents the 16*16 square that is 1 square to the right of the first horizontal block. And the 3 represents the 16*16 square that is 3 squares vertically down from that.

The dot in this chart represents what I'm talking about. One block right, three blocks down.

### |1|2|3|4|5|6|

### |2|3|4|5|6|7|

### |3|•|5|6|7|8|

See, how instead of trying to count how many sixteen-pixels that is, you just make every "1" coordinate have the same value as 16 pixels.

(1, 3) 16*16 squares  would have to be  (16, 48) in pixels.

Oh, god I'm so bad at explaining things.

---

This is basically all I've done to create the chart.

```
    for (int i = 16; i <= 432; i += 16){

        /* Vertical Chart Lines: */ g.drawLine(i, 0, i, HEIGHT*2);
        /* Horizontal Chart Lines: */ g.drawLine(0, i, WIDTH*2, i);

    }
```

I'm working off a Java Canvas, and I set the Preferred Dimension to HEIGHT*2/WIDTH*2.

HEIGHT*2 or WIDTH*2 just represents the pixel-based coordinate all the way at the end of the window/or canvas.

What do I need to do to assign these new coordinates? Would I have to make a new chart?

Oh, please help.

Comment: all you have to do is multiply the coordinates by the size of a square. (and add any borders).  If you have a 1px border between each square, then x2 = x1 * 16 + x1;

Comment: An easy way to conceptualize it is to solve for percentage of one length, and then multiply that percentage by the other length.

Answer (score 0):

Start by organizing everything around the 27*27 dimensions and 16x scaling factor.

So change your code to read:

```
const int scale = 16;
for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++){

    /* Vertical Chart Lines: */ g.drawLine(scale*i, 0, scale*i, HEIGHT*2);
    /* Horizontal Chart Lines: */ g.drawLine(0, scale*i, WIDTH*2, scale*i);

}
```

And, to convert from "chart" to "pixel" coordinates, just do this:

```
int row = getRow(...); /* your code here */
int col = getCol(...); /* your code here */
int x = col * 16;
int y = row * 16;
```

Hope that helps.